# Oracle database data modeler check constraint

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, check-constraint

I need to create a check constraint on a date field on Oracle SQL developer 3.1.07 in domain administration.

I created The check constraint and assigned my domain to field in logical schema. After conversione to relational schema The constraint is not visibile in the DDL preview.

Thanks, 
Mattia

Comment: What is the matter? Can you add this constraint after generating relational schema?

Comment: well, not really. In my opinion is better to add it on logical schema because I can generate the relational more times without loosing my changes.
BTW I resolved, there is a "bug" on SQL Developer 3.1.07.42-1 that prevents you to add check constraints on date fields with domains if added after the creation of the attribute.